# How can I replace each digits by the near digit on right using recursion in C?

Tags: c, recursion

I have a question about replacing digits using recursion.

I'm doing a self practice exercises on recursion and am stuck in one of the questions.

Question: I need to write recursion function which receives int num.
the function need to replace the digits by the digit on left side.
for example: Input `123456` the Output is `214365` (looking from left to right).

I tried to do something like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int Move_to_right(int n) {
    int result;
    int tmp;
    int sum;

    if (n < 10) {
        return n;
    }

    Move_to_right(n / 10);

    return (((n % 100) % 10) * 10) + ((n % 100) / 10);
```

The output is `65`.

I don't know how to make all connect together.
(I want to say that I'm on the beginning of recursion so if you have any tips I will be glad to hear!).

Comment: Hint: `123456 % 100 = 56` and `56 % 10 = 6` and `56 / 10 = 5` and `6 * 10 + 5 = 65`. (Note: using integer math.)

Comment: You are supposed to show a honest attempt...

Comment: Another option is to convert the number to a string.

Comment: Your description is a bit unclear. You are not replacing digits with the neighbor from the right but you are swapping digits. Otherwise `2` should be replaced by `3` instead of `1`.

Comment: The fact that you insist on using recursion makes it sound like this is homework. Homework about recursion, which is supposed to help you practice recursion. How familiar are you with recursion already? Have you already written a recursive function that manipulates digits of a number?

Comment: you are right is a self practice i've been tried for 2 houres to do this with no succsess, I'm not so familiar with recursion and because of that i know practice this subject. also Johnny thanks for your hint i working on this right know, guys if you have any tips for recursion and how to improve on that I will be more than happy Thank you all.

Comment: If you're struggling with recursion, try to write it any other way first and convert it to recursion afterwards. Can you write the code without recursion?

Comment: @prenN ah you want recursion? let me change it then

Comment: RE your update: you are not using the returned value from the recursion call.

Comment: @johnny mopp how can I use it well?

Comment: Broken link :( @johnny moop.

Comment: Site was down. Try this: https://ideone.com/rW4gWL

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char hey[6] = "abcdef";
    char mem;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(hey); i+=2){
        mem=hey[i];
        hey[i]=hey[i+1];
        hey[i+1]=mem;
    }
    printf("%s\n", hey);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Like this?
The output is similar to what you described being badcfe
as a recursion

```
char *leRecursionMeme(char *hey, int a){
    char t;
    if (a>=0)
    {
        t=hey[a];
        hey[a]=hey[a-1];
        hey[a-1]=t;
        hey=leRecurisionMeme(hey, a-2);
    }
    return hey;
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char *hey;
    hey=malloc(6);
    strcpy(hey, "abcdef");
    if (hey==NULL)
    {
        printf("error");
    }
    char mem;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(hey); i+=2){
        mem=hey[i];
        hey[i]=hey[i+1];
        hey[i+1]=mem;
    }
    printf("%s\n", hey);
    hey=leRecursionMeme(hey, 5);
    printf("%s\n", hey);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char hey[6] = "abcdef";` does not leave room for the string terminator `\0`.  Use `char hey[] = "abcdef";` instead.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp im considering just the problem at hand(ie the algorithm) like for example doing something with memory

Comment: I Edit my post, I hope now is more clearly.

Comment: It doesn't matter that you are only using those 6 chars. Functions like `printf`, `strlen`, `strcpy` expect the terminator character.

Comment: strcpy already adds a null terminator on the end plus again the code is just an example in praxis yes its true i should take in count the null string terminator but i think op wants the algorithm not the code in itself